# Error when trying vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Vagrant for my environment and I've got a little issue:

```
$vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base

An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Users/.../base
```

I have initialised my project with `vagrant init` but for some reason `vagrant up` refuses to work.

Comment: The issue I had when I got this error is that I did not `cd` into my project directory

Answer (score 309):

It looks like you may have created a Vagrant project with just `vagrant init`. That will create your Vagrantfile, but it won't have a box defined.

Instead, you could try

`$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` 
`$ vagrant up`

which uses a standard Ubuntu image. The Vagrant website has a [Getting Started](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/) which gives some good examples.

Comment: Gar, that was it. Why does it say "You are now ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment!" then??

Comment: @Matt - Perhaps because you can manually edit the vagrantfile and set which box to use?

Comment: If you've already done `vagrant init` and `vagrant box add` separately, you can just edit Vagrantfile and set config.vm.box to "hashicorp/precise32" or whatever box you want to use.

Comment: I agree--vagrant is very handy, but the user experience is so full of pit traps that are easy to fall into.

Comment: Before trying anything, just run vagrant up command from the same directory where your box files are located. For example, in case of laravel homestead, run vagrant up inside from the Homestead directory.

Answer (score 100):

If you're using OS X and used the standard install, Delete vagrant's old curl and it should now work

`sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl`

Comment: This fixed my issue on mac while working with local and remote boxes

Comment: why on earth does it embed *curl*?

Comment: The `-rf` flag is a bit overkill here. Just `sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl` is enough.
You should try to avoid using the `-r` (= recursive for travelling down directories) and the `-f` (= force without any questions asked) when they are not really needed. They are a powerful and dangerous tool, especially in combination with sudo...

Comment: This worked for me using Vagrant 1.8.7 installed with `brew cask install vagrant`.  The same box file worked fine with same Vagrant version on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You saved my couple of hours. Thanks a lot. How on earth do I know that old curl is the issue !! :/

Answer (score 97):

```
vagrant init laravel/homestead
```

and then

```
vagrant up
```

Was what worked for me.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you ! If someone can explain me why this happen I'll be glad :)

Comment: You need to specify a valid box type. Here are some valid box types: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort&provider=virtualbox&q=debian

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy hehe. greetings from Chile

Comment: use --force with vagrant init if there is already a vagrantfile

Comment: both above 2 answers fixed my problem.  first remove 'curl' folder
run `sudo rm /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl` then run `vagrant init laravel/homestead` and then `vagrant up`

Answer (score 46):

This happened due to having a vagrant file without a defined box name. this happen when you running  **vagrant init** with out a box name parameter.

So you have to delete the Vagrant file then

```
vagrant init box-title
vagrant up
```

I hope this could help!

Comment: The list of available boxes is [here](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort&provider=virtualbox&q=debian)

Comment: this answer saved me from 3 months loop of failing to vagrant that box up, thank you ( i'm on windows 7)

Answer (score 23):

work to me these are the following steps:

- `cd homestead` (in your directory homestead folder) OR `cd Homestead`
- `del vagrantfile` or `rm -Rf Vagrantfile`
- `vagrant init laravel/homestead`
- `vagrant up`

Answer (score 19):

Please run this in your terminal:

```
$ vagrant box list
```

You will see something like `laravel/homestead(virtualbox,x.x.x)`

Next locate your `Vagrantfile` and locate the line that says

```
config.vm.box = "box"
```

replace `box` with the box name when you run `vagrant box list`.

Comment: Note that the "Vagrantfile" is located in: C:\Users\YourUsername if you are using Windows.

Comment: That solved it for me because my box image mentioned in the .kitchen.yml wasn't available anymore. Tricky.

Answer (score 18):

if `"Vagrantfile" already exists in this directory. Remove it before running "vagrant init".`
 error shows then

```
1. rm Vagrantfile
2. vagrant init hashicorp/precise64
3. vagrant up
```

Comment: ==> default: Box 'hashicorp/precise64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install... This allowed for remote install which is what I preferred anyways. I am running on VirtualBox Windows Host with Ubuntu14 client

Comment: This worked for me. So the problem is that when you do `vagrant init`, vagrant defaults to naming your "box" in Vagrantfile to just "base"? And to make that work, you had to specify a non-default Vagrant box name?

Answer (score 15):

I know this is old, but I got exactly the same error. Turns out I was missing [this step](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html) that is clearly in [the documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/index.html).

I needed to edit the `Vagrantfile` to set the `config.vm.box` equal to the image I had downloaded, `hashicorp/precise32`. By default it was set to `base`.

Here's what the documentation says:

> Now that the box has been added to Vagrant, we need to configure our
>   project to use it as a base. Open the Vagrantfile and change the
>   contents to the following:
>
> ```
> Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
>   config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
> end
> ```

Comment: It helps. I am using "vagrant init", the error comes. After specified "hashicorp/precise32" everything seems OK.

Comment: The step is in the official documentation but look at how many authors responding to this question don't include it.

Answer (score 10):

There appears to be something wrong with the embedded curl program in Vagrant. Following the advice above I just renamed it (just in case I wanted it back) and `vagrant up` began to work as expected.

On my mac:

`♪  .vagrant.d  sudo mv /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curlOLD
Password:`

Comment: While I'm not sure if this answers the original question it did help me. Digging into it a bit further I ran the embedded curl command and got `dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/vagrant/embedded/bin/curl_old
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl_old requires version 9.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0`

Comment: I had the same issue with Vagrant 1.8.7 on OSX. The above worked.

Answer (score 6):

i experience this error too.
I think it was because I failed to supply a box_url..

```
vagrant init precise64 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box
```

Comment: Adding `config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box"` to my Vagrantfile fixed it for me.

Answer (score 5):

With me I got an error when run `vagrant up` is (I used Macbook pro, Mac OS: 10.12.1):

`An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try again.
Couldn't open file...`

I tried to delete the `Vagrantfile` in my folder and run:

`vagrant init hashicorp/precise64`

then:

`vagrant up`

It can solved my problem. Hope this can help for someone who face the same problem.

Comment: I tried all of that several times.  The only thing that worked  was renaming curl.  (Mac OS 10.12)

Comment: Worked for me too on a PC running windows 10

Answer (score 5):

I faced same issue when I ran following commands

```
vagrant init
vagrant up  
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /home/...../base
```

I corrected with

```
>vagrant init laravel/homestead
>Vagrant up
```

It worked for me.

Happy coding

Answer (score 5):

The first and most important step before starting a Vagrant is, check which all boxes are present in your system.
Use this command for getting the list of boxes available.

`vagrant box list`

Then move to further process that is, selecting a particular box

`vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64` (I have selected ubuntu/trusty64)

then,

`vagrant up`

Thanks

Comment: "Next, run the [vagrant up] command in your terminal and access your project at http://homestead.test in your browser. Remember, you will still need to add an /etc/hosts file entry for homestead.test or the domain of your choice if you are not using automatic hostname resolution."

Note: this is directly from the Laravel documentation for Homestead. It says nothing about {box-title} in that section of text, so saying passive-aggressive things like "NOTE: It would be great if you do a little bit of Google/Youtube search rather than blindly firing commands :) Thanks" is really not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

well, actually you have to do:

```
vagrant up laravel/homestead
```

because according to homestead walkthrough you've just downloaded it: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead
by:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

so you have to launch the box you mean to use - not some random ubuntu image ;)

Answer (score 4):

i've solved this problem in command line. First change directory to your vagrant file location, then init the Vagrant:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/bionic64
```

**! You will need delete the old *Vagrant* file.**

Then

```
vagrant up
```

Comment: well, you saved someone in 2021 :)

Comment: :D ♥ nice John!

Answer (score 2):

This work for me on Windows 10: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31594225/2400373

But it is necessary to delete the file: `Vagranfile` after use the command:

```
vagrant init precise64 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box
```

And after

```
vagrant up
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, you added a box and started downloading it but interrupted that download, go to `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/` and delete the partial download file, then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by going to folder `.vagrant.d/boxes/` under your home and changed name of the folder from `laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead` to `base`.
And it worked for me.

Please check if virtualization is enabled in your BIOS.

Comment: you should have run "vagrant init laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead"

Answer (score 1):

you can also just add the vm to your machine

```
vagrant box add precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do vagrant init , it replaces the vagrant file in your repo and can give you that error. So I would suggest you copy the original vagrant file from remote or a backup vagrant file and try vagrant up after that.

I came across same issue and I just copied the vagrant file from my remote repo and replaced the vagrant file I was trying to run. This synced the configurations in the vagrant file with the VM.

Answer (score 0):

edit the vagrant file created by `vagrant init` in the same directory and enter the box name in the line `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"` where `ubuntu/trusty64` is your base box.  Now `vagrant up` will download and set `ubuntu/trusty64` as base box for you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below syntax when creating the virtual box:

```
 $ vagrant box add {title} {url}
 $ vagrant init {title}
 $ vagrant up
```

See http://www.vagrantbox.es/

Answer (score 0):

Check Homestead.yaml file carefully.Check if there is any extra space character after line ends.
Then, open gitbash -> go Homestead directory -> command "vagrant up --provision".

Answer (score 0):

Check the following entry in your Vagrantfile

```
Every Vagrant development environment requires a box.
You can search for boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "base"
```

This is the default file setting which is created with **vagrant init** command. But what you need to do is do initialise vagrant environment with an OS box. For instance $**vagrant init *centos/7***. And the Vagrantfile will look something like this:

```
Every Vagrant development environment requires a box.
You can search for boxes at https://vagrantcloud.com/search.
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"
```

This will resolve the error of not found base when doing a **vagrant up**.

Answer (score 0):

try this, works to me:

1. delete all vagrants files in the directory
2. ~# vagrant init --template  --force
3. ~# vagrant up

done!

Answer (score 0):

In the current directory, delete all vagrants files in the directory, then perform init and start vagrant:

```
mv .vagrant .vagrant_old
mv Vagrantfile Vagrantfile_old

vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64  
vagrant up
```

This works.