# vagrant up command fails

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I am learning to use vagrant and I have recently a setup vagrant homestead system on my local machine.

my `homestead.yaml` is in `scr/stubs/` folder.

It looks like this.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /var/www/myhomestead/homestead/ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /var/www/myhomestead/homestead/ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /var/www/sites/
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

When I run "vagrant up" it gives me errors like this.

> amit@Amit:/var/www/myhomestead/homestead$ vagrant up
>
> Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
>   ==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
>       default: Box Provider: virtualbox
>       default: Box Version: >= 0
>   ==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
>       default: Downloading: base
>   An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
>   message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
>   again.
>
> Couldn't open file /var/www/myhomestead/homestead/base

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874260/error-when-trying-vagrant-up)

Comment: Thank you so much Ali Gajani. its work fine now.

Comment: Hope it helped. Always read the docs :)

Comment: yes its helped me a lot.do you have any link related to homestead setup with proper guidelines. because i have searched lots of sites and read lots of docs but i can't find proper solutions. i am just trying and trying and trying.

Comment: Have you seen [Laracasts](http://laracasts.com). Jeffrey will run you down on setting up Vagrant with Laravel.

Comment: Ali Gajani now i am facing new error can you see this ?

Comment: @Amit:/var/www/myhomestead/homestead$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider..
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise32'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'hashicorp/precise32' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead_default_1417506175789_85900
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:450:in `initialize': Permission denied - /home/amit/.vagrant.d/data/lock.fpcollision.lock (Errno::EACCES)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32`. This creates the box not just the project.

Then do `vagrant up` to get the ball rolling.