# Could not open file error with Vagrant Up command

Tags: vagrant

Would anyone know what I can do to solve this? I'm a noob with Vagrant.

```
Crystal:~ Adam$ 
Crystal:~ Adam$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Adding box 'base' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: base
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Users/Adam/base
Crystal:~ Adam$
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have the same situation as described in this SO question: [Error when trying vagrant up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874260/error-when-trying-vagrant-up/24256479#24256479). My answer repeated here:

You may have created a Vagrant project with just `vagrant init`. That will create your Vagrantfile, but it won't have a box defined.

Instead, you could try `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` which uses a standard Ubuntu image. The Vagrant website has a [Getting Started](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/) which gives some good examples.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your Vagrantfile here in case that provides a clue?