# When I run "vagrant up" on Windows 10 then I get errors

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, windows-10

I use Vagrant 1.9.2 and PHP 7.1.3

```
C:\Users\LUONG HUNG\Code>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:66:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): file:///C:/Users/LUONG HUNG/Code/base (URI::InvalidURIError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:475:in `metadata_url?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:81:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:79:in `map'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:79:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:82:in `handle_box'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in `synchronize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'

C:\Users\LUONG HUNG\Code>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'base' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:66:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?): file:///C:/Users/LUONG HUNG/Code/base (URI::InvalidURIError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:72:in `parse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/common.rb:226:in `parse'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:475:in `metadata_url?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:81:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:79:in `map'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_add.rb:79:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:82:in `handle_box'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:42:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in `synchronize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:36:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.9.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you don't have a Vagrant box defined in your Vagrantfile, so it's trying to load the default box 'base' which doesn't exist.

See more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24256479/9965

Comment: No, that's not it. He's got a space in the URI. Vagrant is incapable of handling URI's with white space.