# Getting errors when runnnng vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

I tried some of the solutions from this
[Error when trying vagrant up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874260/error-when-trying-vagrant-up) but still didn't fix my issue. Any help would very appreciated

[image]

Comment: nvm i forgot to cd into vagrant

Answer (score 1):

First time, you just have done `vagrant init` which created a Vagrantfile with a non-existent box named 'base'

you can remove the Vagrantfile and recreate using `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32`

or you can edit the existing Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
  ...
end
```