# when looking up "vagrant up" it gives unsatisfactory information on getting vagrant working

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

when looking for `vagrant up` this is what you get: [Error when trying vagrant up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874260/error-when-trying-vagrant-up/45227911)
. I didn't find this particularly helpful so what the correct answer is you need to go to, **https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search** and find a recent box. **The box written about in the previous answer doesn't exist.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer should be:

1. Run `vagrant init` in the directory you want to use; this will create a file called **Vagrantfile**.
2. After which go to the [url](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) above and find a box you want.
3. Open **Vagrantfile** and under `config.vm.box = prefered/box` edit the box to your preferred box that you found in search.
4. After you have modified your **Vagrantfile** file run the command `vagrant up`. This will download the box.
5. **Success!**